# Jquery Mobile on android link transition double blink

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

Im having a problem with Jquery Mobile after compiling it with Phonegap.

Here is a code snippet:

```
function game() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "#game", { transition: "slideup"} );
}
```

### Page 1:

```
<a onclick="game()" data-role="button">Start game</a>
```

### Page2:

```
<div data-role="page" id="game" data-theme="a">
   ... 
</div>
```

When i click the link "Start Game" it sure does change the page, but it double blinks.  This looks very bad, and im trying to get rid of it.  I like the transision slideup, but i just want the page to change without it looking like its double changing.

Anyone able to help? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phonegap problem with blinking on android is due the poorly performing platforms like Android version 2.x. I advise you to turn them off on that android versions. There are some possible css fixes but I never managed to include them properly in my code.

Transitions can be turned off like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function()
{
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1)
    {
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
        $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
    }
});
```

More about android phones problem can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/

> *After much after a lot of testing and refinement, we’ve decided to use a 3D transform feature test to exclude poorly performing platforms like Android 2.x from the more complex slide, pop and and flip transitions so these will fall back to the default fade for all transitions to ensure a smooth experience.*

Comment: Ohh, this is not good.  So the smooth page change with a fade for example just not is possible on android?

Comment: I tryed out your code you posted.  I cant get it to work.  My site still double flashes/blinks.

I created a JS file and included it external as the last JS file that where to be included.

Did i do soemthing wrong?

Comment: Here's an post with needed example: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-use-document-bind-mobileinit, worst case scenario first test if mobileinit event is working, then test if your user agent is Android.

Comment: ok im going to test with a simple alert() function if the code fires of step by step on my phone.

Comment: I did 2 tests.  One with a smaller version of my code, and then it worked.

I did one with the full package, and then it dident work.

I think that maybe there are some script code that intercepts with the solution u posted.  

I would need additinal testing time in order to work this out.  It wont be today, but tomorrow.

Ill be back :

Comment: im back home now, on it again :)

Comment: @Gajotres Could you tell where exactly I should add this piece of code?

Comment: Mobileinit must be initialized before jQuery Mobile js initialization but after jQuery js initialization. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: @Gajotres I dont use phonegap but the transition doubles on android google 4.2 phone, do you think this is normal?

Comment: This could be an error in your code, some errors can cause multiple transitions. Stupid I know but fixable.

Comment: @Gajotres I created a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692671/transition-effect-doubles-on-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0):

Solution found, thanks to Gajotres.

I found that i had to include the transition disable script before jquery mobile, which in terms are a bit weird.  It would be more logical to include it after, however it works now, and im happy :)

The solution:

```
<script src="js/disableTransition.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```